# Как связать Чекбокс и CSS в Ucoz?

Tags: html, ucoz

Есть магазин на Ucoz, в разделе "Оформление заказа" есть способ оплаты. Видоизменил с помощью css форму оплаты.
Выглядела изначально так:
[image: Изначальный вид]
После сделал так:
[image: Вид после]

Так вот в чем собственно проблема, при наведении мышки нужно жать на "Заголовок" или "Чекбокс" например: Заголовок "Банковская карта" или "Чекбокс" которая рядом, что-бы выбрать. 
Вопрос собственно вот в чем, как связать так что-бы можно было нажимать по всему периметру оболочки CSS а не только на заголовок или чекбокс?

Находится это все в переменной $PAYMENT_LIST$

Comment: Надеюсь помогут!

Comment: html-код хотя бы покажите

Comment: https://multisoc.ru посмотрите, понятия не имею как его достать из переменной! Код смотрите на странице оформления заказа!

Comment: «Код смотрите» — так вы его в текст вопроса не стесняйтесь прикрепить

Comment: О, наконец-то вопрос по uCoz, а я уж думал не будет меня преследовать :D

Answer (score 0):

Увы, с онлайн-магазином на uCoz я не работал.. Так что не подскажу где вставлять данный код, но ищите что-то типо "страница оплаты"..

Там перед `</body>` вставьте следующий код:

```
<script>
  $('#payments-list').on('click', 'tr', function(){
    var label = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]');
    if(label.prop('checked') == false) {
      label.prop('checked', 'true');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Это Jquery код, но саму библиотеку подключать ненужно, uCoz изначально её использует.

Вот пример как это будет работать.

```js
$('#payments-list').on('click', 'tr', function(){
  var label = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]');
  if(label.prop('checked') == false) {
    label.prop('checked', 'true');
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

#payments-list tr,
#delivery-list tr {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#payments-list th,
#delivery-list th {
  width: 35px;
}

.methods-list td {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left !important;
  left: 5px;
}

элемент {}

#payments-list .label,
#delivery-list .label {
  color: #777;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table.methods-list tr {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(52, 152, 219, .1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

label,
.label {
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

table.methods-list tr:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(231, 76, 60);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="payments-list" class="methods-list">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="payment-block-2" valign="top">
      <th><input type="radio" id="pay-type-2" class="payment-item" name="payment" value="2" onclick="shEvOrd('payment',this)" checked=""></th>
      <td><label class="label" for="pay-type-2">Банковская карта</label>5% комиссия</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="payment-block-4" valign="top">
      <th><input type="radio" id="pay-type-4" class="payment-item" name="payment" value="4" onclick="shEvOrd('payment',this)"></th>
      <td><label class="label" for="pay-type-4">QIWI</label>7% комиссия</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="payment-block-5" valign="top">
      <th><input type="radio" id="pay-type-5" class="payment-item" name="payment" value="5" onclick="shEvOrd('payment',this)"></th>
      <td><label class="label" for="pay-type-5">Яндекс Деньги</label>7% комиссия</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="payment-block-7" valign="top">
      <th><input type="radio" id="pay-type-7" class="payment-item" name="payment" value="7" onclick="shEvOrd('payment',this)"></th>
      <td><label class="label" for="pay-type-7">Free-Kassa</label>4% комиссия</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="payment-block-8" valign="top">
      <th><input type="radio" id="pay-type-8" class="payment-item" name="payment" value="8" onclick="shEvOrd('payment',this)"></th>
      <td><label class="label" for="pay-type-8">RoboKassa</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло

Comment: @Bozak, не за что, взамен спасибо можете нажать на галочку рядом с моим ответом)